# Choose the correct word

Tags: meaning, prepositions

There are some questions in my english book which i didnt know 
》pandas look gentle ,but in fact they are quite (fierce -thoughtful-intelligent-graceful)
( i think due to the word but it should be fierce but panadas arent fierce so is it intelligent?)

》the fans in the football stadium cheered for the players on the (ring -court- pitch)
( i think it is court but  i want to know when i chose ring?)

》my brother and I are always fighting .... something (is it (for) or (on) or sth else?) (What is the difference between fight for and on)

》my brother brought home a kitten that he had found on the street , we cared ... it together ( for or about)? And what is the difference?

Comment: Your question should reflect your own effort. This looks your asking for answers to a exam or homework. Please edit the question to address this. I am flagging the question as "off topic".

Comment: @Cardinal Currently Im preparing for my English exam and while I was studying I found those questions and wanted to check my answers,so it isnt a homework neither an exam ..by the way I am going to edit my post and write the answer that I guess its right .

Comment: @Cardinal you can tell me what I can do in order to know the answers without breaking any rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Fierce*** Thoughtful, intelligent and graceful could be associated with "gentle", however fierce is not. The *but* in this sentence suggests an opposing thought to what you would assume about pandas.

***Court/Pitch*** Both work for this; you would say *in* the ring. A ring is used in fighting or martial arts (boxing, wrestling). A court is something like tennis or basketball (a sport with a smaller size than a pitch). A pitch is for sports such as football (soccer and American), rugby, cricket.

***For*** In this instance, fighting *for* something means you are fighting to win something, potentially a prize. You may also fight *about* something, if you are arguing for example. Fighting *on* something is rarely used and would only make sense in a specific circumstance, "we are fighting *on* Tuesday".

***For*** If you care *for* something, you have responsibility to maintain its health and well-being. If you care *about* something, it means you have interest or passion in a concept, e.g. "I care *about* politics."